# How do I implement CopyMemory (VB6) in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a line of code:

```
Dim buf(1 To 255) As Byte

          a$ = "hello"   

Call CopyMemory(buf(1), ByVal a$, Len(a$))
```

I want to execute it in C#.NET. What is the alternative for the above line in C#.NET?

Comment: Take a look at [System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see a sample

Comment: Can you tell me how to obtain the address of the byte array using the VarPtr() intrinsic function and copy the address and length of the byte array into a COPYDATASTRUCT structure in C#.NET

Comment: Why do you need it in a `COPYDATASTRUCT`? `CopyMemory` has nothing to do with that. Or is your question really "How do I use WM_COPYDATA from C#?"?

Comment: Copy a string data in c#.net and pass it to a vb6 app

Answer (score 1):

```
string aString = "hello";
byte[] theBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aString);
```

See [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) and [Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue:-

```
string aString = text;
            byte[] theBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aString);
//to copy to memory use the following:-
            // Marshal the managed struct to a native block of memory.
            int myStructSize = theBytes.Length;
            IntPtr pMyStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myStructSize);
            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(theBytes, 0, pMyStruct, myStructSize);

...........
}
```

This can then be picked up from the memory by other application..